# How to display an error when saving a product variation in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I understand that saving a product variation is done via AJAX. I'm now using the hook `woocommerce_save_product_variation` to add some customized code to upload the product variation image to a third-party server. In case there's an error during upload, how could I tell the WP admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `admin_notices` hook. Here is an article explaining how to use it. I think the section "Generating Notices Via User Actions" would pertain to your situation.

https://wpmudev.com/blog/adding-admin-notices/

Modified example code from that section:

```
if( $error_uploading_image ) {
  add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_image_error_notice' );
}

function my_image_error_notice() {
  ?>
  <div class="update-nag notice">
      <p><?php _e( 'There was an error uploading the image.', 'my_plugin_textdomain' ); ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```